# Maximum Liklehood estimator for Bernoulli distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

Consider the following :
[image]

I am trying to find the unknown parameter theta using the Maximum likelihood method but I am stuck here :
summation of i= 1 to i=d (xi/thetai  -  (1-xi)/1-thetai )
I cant continue from here, so please help me to solve.

Comment: Hi: Take the log. This way, it turns into a sum and then exponents come down to the terms raising them. This makes taking the derivative cleaner.  Note that taking the log is okay because it's it preserves the maximum of the function.

Comment: @mlofton  I have done so and here where I am stuck  summation of i= 1 to i=d (xi/thetai - (1-xi)/1-thetai )

Comment: @Xi'an Done added

Comment: No idea why you’re doing division there. But find the maximum. It’s convex, so there’s one global optimum. Find it however you want: some iterative method, the known closed-form solution, or taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero.

Comment: Hi: I don't follow because, if you took the log, then there should be sums of  logs in your likelihood.

Comment: @mlofton yes bro There is a sum as I told you  : summation of i= 1 to i=d (xi/thetai - (1-xi)/1-thetai ) . There is no logs because already i have taken the ln of the function and I have done the dervatives so summation of i= 1 to i=d (xi/thetai - (1-xi)/1-thetai )=0 .

Comment: Hi: I was going to work out the details but then I saw below. Is that okay ? He did it for one likelihood but you could put a summation around the whole and obtain $\hat{p}$ using the sum approach.

Comment: @mlofton Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad to help but all credit goes to user1483.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a multivariate binomial distribution where all the variables are independent.  The ML may be calculated for each variable separately.

Consider the $i$ variable and let $\theta_1 = p$.  Let $y_1,\ y_2 \ \dots,y_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from this distribution.  Then let $j=\sum_{k=1}n y_k$. Then you may show that the Liklihood corresponding to the bernouli distribution is a  Binomial distribution. i.e.

$$L = C_j^n p^j (1-p)^{n-j}$$
$$\log (L) = \log C_j^n + j \log p + (n-j) log(1-p)$$

Differentiate and solve to get the ML estimator of p

$$\hat{p} = \frac{j}{n}$$

and similarly for the other parameters.

You may of course proceed by neglecting independence but your algebra will be very complicated